# apache spark 2.1.1 MetaException(message:file:/user/hive/warehouse/person is not a directory or unable to create one)

Tags: apache-spark

I have Apache Spark 2.1.1. I am using Spark SQL. This is how I initialize Spark:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
           .builder()
           .master("spark://ipaddress")
           .appName("Java Spark Hive Example")
           .enableHiveSupport()
           .getOrCreate();
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Person(name STRING , id INT) row format delimited fields terminated BY ',' lines terminated BY '\n' tblproperties(skip.header.line.count=1)
```

I am getting:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:file:/user/hive/warehouse/person is not a directory or unable to create one);
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:98)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.createTable(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:191)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.createTable(SessionCatalog.scala:248)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateTableCommand.run(tables.scala:116)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)

I have default file system set as HDFS in core-site.xml file under spark/conf

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
      <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I do not understand why Spark is creating warehouse under localSystem rather than HDFS.

Comment: The Hadoop client does not care about `$SPARK_HOME/conf/`. It cares about any directory that it finds in its CLASSPATH. That's why Spark expects an env variable named **`HADOOP_CONF_DIR`** that points to the location of Hadoop conf files, and that dir is added to the CLASSPATH passed to the Hadoop client libs.

Comment: Plus, are you really sure that `fs.default.name` is a valid Hadoop property?????????????

Comment: Thanks. I see fs.default.name is deprecated and replaced by fs.defaultFS.